# Uniqueness of the True cofinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, products

Why is the **true cofinality** [here](https://shelah.logic.at/files/95928/E23.pdf) on the page 220
in the definition 5.7(5) **unique** ?

Comment: If you had two different true cofinalities $\kappa<\lambda$ for $P$ you could use the cofinal $\kappa$-sequence in $P$ to build a cofinal $\kappa$-sequence in $\lambda$, since every element of the $\lambda$ sequence in $P$ has an upper bound in the $\kappa$-sequence, which is impossible. I don't have time to spell out the details, but it should be reasonably intuitive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that a partial order $\mathcal{P}$ have two $\leq_{\mathcal{P}}$-increasing sequences $A:=\{p_i:i<\lambda\}$ and $B:=\{q_i:i<\kappa\}$ such that that $\lambda<\kappa$ and both of them are witness for $tcf(\mathcal{P})$. So, you can build an alternating sequence between the elements of $A$ and $B$, $p_0<q_{\alpha_0}<p_{\beta_1}<q_{\alpha_1}<...$ where $q_{\alpha_i}>p_i$. But, as $\kappa$ is regular and $\lambda<\kappa$ the sequence $\{q_{\alpha_i}:i\leq\lambda\}$ is bounded in $B$. Let $q\in B$ such that $q_{\alpha_i}<q$. So, for every $p_i\in A$ we have that $p_i<q$. This implies that $A$ fails to be a witness of $tcf(\mathcal{P})$.

Comment: Right, an alternation is the answer. I didn't notice that your $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ are assumed to be regular. Thank you for an explanation.

Comment: In your answer the last but one line should read $p_i<q$ and not $p<q$, right ?

Comment: @user122424 yes, I fixed the typo.